# Define one prop as optional if another one is of specific enum type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Component prop type:

```
interface IRequireUserPermits {
  minimalRequiredRole: UserRoles;
  allowedPermissions: UserPermissions[];
}
```

`UserRoles` is an enum:

```
export enum UserRoles {
  SUPERADMIN = "SUPERADMIN",
  ADMIN = "ADMIN",
  AGENT = "AGENT",
}
```

How can I define `allowedPermissions` prop required **only if** the `minimalRequiredRole` prop is `UserRoles.AGENT`? Or the other way around - how to make prop optional **only if** the `minimalRequiredRole` prop is either `UserRoles.SUPERADMIN` or `UserRoles.ADMIN`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions). Instead of *interface* let's use *type* for `IRequireUserPermits`:

```
type IRequireUserPermits =
  | {
      minimalRequiredRole: UserRoles.AGENT;
      allowedPermissions: UserPermissions[];
    }
  | {
      minimalRequiredRole: UserRoles.SUPERADMIN | UserRoles.ADMIN;
    };
```

Testing:

```
const case1: IRequireUserPermits = {
  minimalRequiredRole: UserRoles.AGENT,
  allowedPermissions: [], // no error
};

const case2: IRequireUserPermits = {
  minimalRequiredRole: UserRoles.ADMIN,
  allowedPermissions: [], // error
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwKoGdhQEoQA2wWcA3gFBxwDKGACgKJ4CCAIgLICSAcnALxwA5HSatOvIQBoqcdtz6Ch8yTOosA4ox4AVAcM3ad0igF8KFGAE8wwTDij1cqAJZYsLiIlKDK1AIaEhBAA7sAAJgBccABmgTgA3GZJljZ2XHjAAI7ILlDA2LhOUK4wPrIAPuSy1NSuiC6ogZk5eREExNGF+EQkAHSGukm1tYHBYeHFru6e3l0OU24eXlgA2gC6w7Xm1FV+I3D1jc3ZufnhHcDzuJdYfaLMKnxV3bcDEjxb1KYpAMYr8F+-hwAEZohlTm1uosyvp9kcmoQWmd2r1rj1iHdBjo1HAxqEIosZitohspHAAPQUuCICAIKBQaDJCz-byA4HAABM4ORUIWzhcsN8sgRJ1a50u6LeT1x+ImROWczgZMp1NwjKgzKAA)

Comment: Thank you sir. This works well except one little thing. If I take your solution and define destructured object like this: `{ minimalRequiredRole, allowedPermissions}: TRequireUserPermits`, TS will complain `Property 'allowedPermissions' does not exist on type 'TRequireUserPermits'.`. I can solve this easily by adding optional allowedPermissions property to the other union type, but that makes it no difference to the solution in which I would just make that property optional and not use discriminated unions. EDIT: I can actually solve this by not destructuring. I'm accepting this as answer.

Comment: The compiler does what it should do. You want to have `allowedPermissions` only in specific cases, since in the other case it is not there you get the error. You have two options. 1. before destructing check if the enum value matches then destruct. 2. Add `allowedPermissions?: never;` to the case where this field shouldn't be

Comment: Thank you! Will work it out with `never`